# Typeorm of sql query

Tags: sql, node.js, typeorm, freetexttable

This query works well on the database, however I'm not able to make it work by using typeorm createQueryBuilder.

```
SELECT *
FROM content 
INNER JOIN FreeTextTable(content, *, 'text') AS KEY_TBL
    ON content.id = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
ORDER BY KEY_TBL.RANK DESC
```

Could you please help me out here?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm trying to use typeorm on a nodejs backend to query my sql database, however I wasn't able to use "freetexttable" to query data. My question is how should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

For those facing the same issue. I was unable to find a solution to use FREETEXTTABLE with typeorm, so I had to implement it using raw SQL.